# Are there words/phrases to describe the things that have been fixed firmly in the same place for a long time that it looks as if impossible to change?

Tags: word-request

e.g. to describe the US dollar as the world's currency, or English as the most used language, that are unwavering/stable/held securely (long-standingly) and not likely to fall from their position

I have Googled it but it seems that it is too specific a question that I found no answer to it

Comment: Maybe, *long established as*, or *set in stone*.

Comment: Maybe *entrenched*?